# How to put linebreaks between list elements within the same Pandas dataframe cell?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a column of lists of strings. How do I make the list elements show up line by line in Pandas within the same row (and same cell)?

Given a dataframe like this:

```
+-------+-----------------------------------+
| col_a |               col_b               |
+-------+-----------------------------------+
| A     | ['string1', 'string2', 'string3'] |
| B     | ['string4', 'string5', 'string6'] |
+-------+-----------------------------------+
```

I want to make it show up like this:

```
+-------+---------+
| col_a |  col_b  |
+-------+---------+
| A     | string1 |
|       | string2 |
|       | string3 |
| B     | string4 |
|       | string5 |
|       | string6 |
+-------+---------+
```

Note I want to keep them within the same cell, just add linebreaks between the elements, and optionally remove the square brackets and quotes if possible.

I tried this:

`df['col_b'].apply(lambda x: ('\n'.join(i) for i in x), axis=1)`

But it is getting `TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'`

Comment: If your pandas version is `>= 0.25.0`  Just use `df.explode('col_b')`

Comment: Besides that, you dont need `apply`. Use `df['col_b'].str.join('\n')`

Comment: @Erfan I don't want them in separate rows, so different to that other question, and so I think `explode` is not appropriate here.

Comment: @Erfan `df['col_b'].str.join('\n')` does the job. Thanks. Though I need to swap `\n` with `<br>` and then call `.style` on the dataframe to make it appear as I want.

Comment: You should post the full correct answer yourself and accept that one. Now someone who has the same question will not find the correct answer.

Comment: **Do you only want to change the (visual) formatting, not string-replace the actual cell contents?** Generally people who ask this only want to change the formatting. pandas has methods for that: custom formatters, Styling, `to_string()`, `to_html()`...

Comment: When you say 'linebreak' do you mean HTML <br> or just newline '\n'?

Comment: @smci My desired output will be in HTML format, so joining with `<br>` will be sufficient. Calling `.style` is just an additional step I need inside Jupyter notebook which I'm working in to get the cell output to display as it would when the HTML is rendered.

Comment: @smci I was thinking of converting the lists into long strings with \n between each list element, and then convert that to HTML. Maybe there is a way to do that. But using <br> worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these work:

`df['col_b'].apply(lambda x: '<br>'.join(x)).style`

`df['col_b'].str.join('<br>').style`

I'm using the latter as it is shorter.

Note I'm working inside Jupyter notebook, and it needs `<br>` instead of `\n` and then calling `.style` to display the way I want it to.

Answer (score 2):

Try simply:

```
df['col_b'].apply(lambda x: ('\n'.join(x))
```

Your for loop iterates over the single strings inside the lists which rather than join the whole list.

Comment: Thanks. Though I need to swap `\n` with `<br>` and then call `.style` on the dataframe to make it appear as I want.